# how to retrieve Facebook friend's group name?

Tags: ios, facebook

Facebook SDK 3.+ has requestForMyFriends, and return FBGraphUser but it doesn't have a group name property, is there a way to get all the groups belongs to the user?

Answer (score 2):

You could easily grab all of a user's groups using the FB Open Graph and SLRequests. Ensure that you've already authenticated and then make the call like this:

```
NSURL *groups = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups"];

SLRequest *retrieveGroups = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:groups parameters:nil];

[retrieveGroups performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
{
//responseData contains your groups 
}];
```